# NSPredicate throwing exception while trying to fetch data from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have the following CoreDataModel:

[image: Core Data Model]

Each park is related to a set of inspections and each inspection is inversely related to the park. I am loading the data into the park from a web service response. So, from inside the NSManagedObject subclass of Park, I need to query for all the related Inspections(there will be only one satisfying that condition) with a particular `inspectionID` and `assigmentID` and create it if not exists, for which I used the following function:

```
- (Inspection *)getInspectionWithId:(NSInteger)inspectionId assignmentId:(NSInteger)assignmentId {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    //Crash in the following line
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (self.inspections.inspectionID == %d AND self.inspections.assignmentID == %d)", inspectionId, assignmentId];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [[[Model sharedModel] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (array == nil || array.count < 1) {
        NSEntityDescription *inspectionEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Inspection" inManagedObjectContext:[[Model sharedModel] managedObjectContext]];
        return (Inspection *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:inspectionEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[Model sharedModel] managedObjectContext]];
    }
    else {
        return (Inspection *)array[0];
    }
}
```

But the app is crashing with the following exception. I am not sure of the condition in the predicate to use for this. Can anyone please help?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "ANY (self.inspections.inspectionID == %d AND
>   self.inspections.assignmentID == %d)"'

Comment: You can't refer to a property of a 1-many relationship.  `self.inspections.inspectionID` isn't valid.

Comment: @Avi Can you please tell me the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is there no other way using predecate or something than looping through the set?

Comment: You probably need to use `SUBQUERY()`.  I don't have time to write a complete answer.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for getting me started. I will try that one.